# setImageMatrix only working in Touch Event Android

Tags: android, matrix, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I'm trying to make a custom map with a modified relativelayout.

I'm using matrices and touch events.

**First Problem**

Every `setImageMatrix()` outside of my Touch Event are not doing anything but the ones in the event are working.

The problem is that I need to be able to set points on the map before the user touches the screen.

I've tried `invalidate()` on pretty much every view and it's not doing anything.

**Second problem**

I have made a custom class extending ImageView and it's not displaying at all.

Constructor:

```
public OverlayPoint(Context context,JSONObject obj) {
    super(context);
    this.obj = obj;

    this.setImageResource(R.drawable.interet);

    this.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams 
            (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    myMatrix = new Matrix();
}
```

The call in the extended relativelayout :

```
public void addPoint(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException
{
    OverlayPoint vv = new OverlayPoint(getContext(),obj);
    Upoint pp = new Upoint(obj.getDouble("latitude"),obj.getDouble("longitude"));
    vv.setXY(pp.getX(), pp.getY());
    this.addView(vv);
    myOverlays.add(vv);
    Log.d("Overlay","Point added to array");
    Log.d("Overlay", myOverlays.toString());


    GlobalState gs = (GlobalState)  ((VTTMatapediaActivity)this.getContext()).getApplication();
    gs.addPoint(obj);
    this.invalidate();
}
```

**Edit:** Forgot to mention I was using a ViewFlipper to flip views. But I juste tried Waiting for the animation to finish to call a setImageMatrix and nothing happens...

Thanks